# Mostrar atributo específico no Select usando Python e Django

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.0

Em `models.py` criei as seguintes tabelas:

```
class UsuarioAdicionalPlano(models.Model):
    quantidade = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    preco = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=13)

class ConfiguracoesDoPlano(models.Model):
    plano = models.ForeignKey('login.Plano', related_name='plano', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    usuarios_adicional = models.ForeignKey('login.UsuarioAdicionalPlano', related_name='usuario_adicional', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Em `forms.py`

```
class ConfiguracoesDoPlanoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ConfiguracoesDoPlano
        fields = ('plano', 'notas_adicional', 'usuarios_adicional')
        widgets = {
            'plano': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'usuarios_adicional': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    }
        labels = {
            'plano': 'Plano escolhido',
            'usuarios_adicional': 'Usuários adicionais',
    }
```

E no arquivo `.html` tenho o seguinte `Select`
O `form` vem de `ConfiguracoesDoPlanoForm` da tabela `ConfiguracoesDoPlano`

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>{{form.usuarios_adicional.label}}</label><strong style="color:red;"> *</strong>
       {% if form.usuarios_adicional.errors %}<label class="error">{% for error in form.usuarios_adicional.errors %}{{error}}{% endfor %}</label>{% endif %}
       <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
           <div class="form-line">
           {{form.usuarios_adicional}}
           </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Porém o meu `select` está aparecendo com os valores `'UsuarioAdicionalPlano object (0)'` , `'UsuarioAdicionalPlano object (1)'`, e assim por diante.

[image: Como aparece o meu select]

Como eu faço para que os valores do `Select` sejam o valor do atributo `quantidade`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isso não esta relacionado a função **__str__** da classe? Tente declarar a função **__str__** retornando a saída que você quer no modelo *UsuarioAdicionalPlano*, algo parecido com isso:

```
def __str__():
   return this.quantidade
```

Comment: Funcionou usando a função `def __str__(self): return str(self.quantidade)`